# Multiple subdomains use same site code

Tags: php, codeigniter, subdomain

I am trying to make a site where users, after registration, have a personalized page with a subdomain. However, I want the same main site code to be used and content that is displayed to be generated depending on what subdomain the user visits, not by having copies of the code for each subdomain.

If it is unclear, what I want is similar to how blog hosting sites have subdomains, setting and everything without the need to do a fresh installation of the actual blog script.

I have PHP, MySQL knowledge and I use Codeigniter as my PHP Framework. What I do not know is how to achieve this  effect without duplicating files.

Comment: Run print_r($_SESSION). You will see that you can detect what hostname is used to access the site. So, if  you have all the subdomains pointed at the same web directory, the PHP code can be customized based on the hostname. You can have a folder of options for each hostname, changing the CSS and such.

Comment: @PetrePopescu, been a long time, did you find any better approach for this? I am also looking to achieve something similar using laravel. 

In my case there will be super admin (owner of website) who will register subdomains and add their details in the database through a panel, and when users visit each subdomain I will add middleware to check the domain and fetch the data accordingly and show to the users.

I am just curious to know the approach you used and to hear some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/profile?id=$1 [R=301]
```

NOTE: Not sure if this'll work. Wrote it on the spot.

Make sure you have the profile system so that it loads id with a GET request of the /profile/ directory.